# Yes/No field in JSON view formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, json-formatting, yes-no-field, view-formatting

This is about JSON formatted views (not columns) in modern SharePoint online.

**List A** has a Yes/No field. The values show as Yes or No in the view. When I format the view and show the field value using `"txtContent": "[$MyField]"`, it shows as `true` or `false`. (the screenshot has two of these side by side, several records)

[image]

In order to conditionally format the elements, I can use the field on its own, since it evaluates to True or False. No operator required.

```
"class": "=if([$MyField],'sp-field-severity--good','sp-field-severity--blocked')"
```

**List B** also has a Yes/No field. The values show as Yes or No in the view. When I format the view and show the field value using `"txtContent": "[$MyYesNoField]"`, it shows as `Yes` or `No`.

[image]

In order to conditionally format the elements, I have to use a comparison operator and compare with Yes or No as text strings:

```
"class": "=if([$MyYesNoField]=='Yes','sp-field-severity--good','sp-field-severity--blocked')"
```

**What causes the difference between these two columns** in the two different lists and how can it be influenced?

When I download the lists to Excel, the columns all show True/False.

Both lists are populate with a Flow that sets the column values to True/False, not Yes/No.

The problem is that a condition in JSON that is based on the value of the yes/no field will work fine if it is a true/false value, but the view will not render correctly **in a list web part** when the value is Yes/No and the condition needs to compare with text.

Therefore, I need the Yes/No column to internally store the values as TRUE/FALSE, not as Yes/No.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please check again if it is Yes/No field or Choice field? Also, what is the template you are using for both lists? Is there any specific differences in both columns settings??

Comment: @Ganeshsanap Believe me, I checked. It’s a yes/no field.   No list template. Column in list A was added via the modern view UI in the view. Column in list B was added via the list Settings >add column command.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the same steps to create two Yes/No columns, one from modern view (named `FromView`) and another from list settings page(named `FromSettings`).

Tried below combinations and it is working fine for me:

**Yes/No column created from Modern View**:

```
{
    "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "hideSelection": true,
    "hideColumnHeader": true,
    "rowFormatter": {
        "elmType": "div",
        "txtContent": "[$FromView]",
        "attributes": {
        "class": "=if([$FromView], 'sp-field-severity--good','sp-field-severity--blocked')"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Yes/No column created from List settings Page**:

```
{
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "[$FromSettings]",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "=if([$FromSettings], 'sp-field-severity--good','sp-field-severity--blocked')"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added more Yes/No columns to the list. They all show as Yes or No in the Json formatter. Must be something wrong with that list.

Comment: Is it normal modern SharePoint List or any other type of list?

Comment: Normal list. Create with New > List. It's probably corrupt. I created another list that doesn't have the problem and have abandoned this one.

Comment: Please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.